# Optimizing binary search tree

Tags: performance, c, tree

How could I optimize this binary search tree?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct NODE
{
    int info;
    struct NODE *right;
    struct NODE *left;
    struct NODE *parent;
};
typedef struct NODE node;

node *createnode(node *temp,int number)
{
    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->info=number;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->parent=NULL;
return temp;
}

node *insert(node *head,int number)
{
    node *temp;
    temp=createnode(temp,number);
    node *traverse=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        temp->parent=NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        while(traverse!=NULL)
        {
            if(number < traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->left==NULL)
                {
                    traverse->left=temp;
                    temp->parent=traverse;
                    break;
                }
                traverse=traverse->left;
            }
            else if(number>traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->right==NULL)
                {
                    traverse->right=temp;
                    temp->parent=traverse;
                    break;
                }
                traverse=traverse->right;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
return head;
}

node *find(node *head,int number)               // finding the position of the element which we want to delete
{
    node *traverse=head;
    if(traverse==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        while(traverse!=NULL)
        {
            if(number<traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->left==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Number not found\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
                traverse=traverse->left;
            }
            else if(number>traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->right==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Number not found\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
                traverse=traverse->right;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
return traverse;
}
int find_children(node *temp)                   // finding the number of children of the the node that we want to delete
{
    int count=0;
    if(temp->left!=NULL)
        count+=1;
    if(temp->right!=NULL)
        count+=1;
return count;
}
node *delete(node *head,int number)               //deleting the node
{
    int children;
    node *temp=head;
    temp=find(temp,number);
    if(temp==NULL)
        return head;
    else if(head->left==NULL && head->right==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        children=find_children(temp);
        if(children==0)
        {
            if(temp->parent->left==temp)
            {
                temp->parent->left=NULL;
            }
            else if(temp->parent->right==temp)
            {
                temp->parent->right=NULL;
            }
        }
        if(children==1)
        {
            if(temp->parent==NULL)
            {
                if(temp->right!=NULL)
                {
                    temp->right->parent=NULL;
                    head=temp->right;
                }
                else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                {
                    temp->left->parent=NULL;
                    head=temp->left;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp->parent->left==temp)
                {
                    if(temp->right!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->right->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->left=temp->right;
                    }
                    else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->left->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->left=temp->left;
                    }
                }
                if(temp->parent->right==temp)
                {
                    if(temp->right!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->right->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->right=temp->right;
                    }
                    else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->left->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->right=temp->left;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(children==2)
        {
            node *temp1;
            node *temp2;
            temp1=temp;
            temp2=temp->right;
            while(temp2->left!=NULL)
            {
                temp1=temp2;
                temp2=temp2->left;
            }
            temp->info=temp2->info;
            if(temp1->left==temp2)
            {
                    temp1->left=temp2->left;
            }
            else
            {
                temp1->right=temp2->right;
            }
        }

    }
return head;
}
void printing(node *head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return ;
    printing(head->left);
       printf("%d ",head->info);
    printing(head->right);
}

int main()
{
    node *head;
    int number,choice;
    printf("Choose one of the option\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1.Enter a element\n2.Delete an element\n3.print tree\n4.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                scanf("%d",&number);
                head=insert(head,number);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                scanf("%d",&number);
                head=delete(head,number);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                printing(head);
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I optimize this binary search tree?

Higher-level suggestions:

- Forward declaration of the supported operations would be nice, so I can see them at a glance without scrolling through the entire post
- Given the current supported operations, `NODE` doesn't really need the `parent`. You could refactor and simplify without it
- In `insert`, you first create allocate a node, but it might not be used if the value already exists in the tree
- A naming convention for types would be good. `node`, in particular, is commonly used as variable name when working with trees, so it's confusing that it's actually a type
- `find_children` is poorly named. `count_children` would be better

Lower-level suggestions:

- `temp` is a poor name. Everywhere you used `temp`, `node` would have been better (unfortunately it was taken as a type name, as mentioned earlier)
- Instead of `info` a more common name to use for the data in a tree node is, well, `data`
- In many places you have `if (condition) { return ...; } else { ...; }`. When the `if` part returns, the `else` statement can be eliminated, which would often let you reduce the indent level of the rest of the routine, making it more readable
- `return 0` is unnecessary in `main`, the compiler adds that automatically
- It's really odd to unindent the `return` statements. Usually it's at the same indent level as the body of the routine
- It's more readable to put spaces around operators, for example `temp->left = NULL` instead of `temp->left=NULL`, and `if (head == NULL)` instead of `if(head==NULL)`, and `if (number > traverse->info)` instead of `if(number>traverse->info)`

The logic in most of the routines can be simplified.
For example, consider this snippet in `find`:

> ```
> node *traverse=head;
> if(traverse==NULL)
>     return NULL;
> else
> {
>     while(traverse!=NULL)
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> return traverse;
> ```

Could be simplified as this, without even knowing what's inside that `while`:

```
node *traverse = head;
while (traverse != NULL)
{
    // ...
}
return traverse;
```

Going further, the implementation of the routine can be reduced to a much more simplified form:

```
node *traverse = head;
while (traverse != NULL)
{
    if (number < traverse->info)
    {
        traverse = traverse->left;
    }
    else if (number > traverse->info)
    {
        traverse = traverse->right;
    }
    else
    {
        return traverse;
    }
}
printf("Number not found\n");
return NULL;
```

If you look closely, the other routines can be simplified as well.